# Retrieving data of only a particular user using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Summary:**
I'm working on a simple MERN stack to-do app with login functionality. I haven't implemented login yet, because I don't know how to go about it. Each to-do item is currently stored as an individual document (having attributes _id, name and description) in an 'items' collection. I'm using mongoose.

**Question:** How do I update my database structure so as to store login credentials for each registered user and also so that I can fetch only the to-do's of the logged-in user? One way I could do it is by storing user credentials in a separate collection, and adding a "userID" attribute to each to-do document, so that I can fetch them by userID:

```
item
{ _id:39v6m8356nv45435
  title:"Buy milk",
  description:"no description",
  userID:09239bfd234g }
```

Or should I store user credentials and all of their to-do's in a single document? If I do it like this, how do I access individual to-do items from the array, or add more items to the array?

```
user
{ _id:980w3709b476jh,
  username:"John",
  password:"weak",
  todos: [{todo1},{todo2}]
}
```

Or, should I do something else?

I am not looking for a perfect answer, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated. Any articles or videos would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming, you dont have to share ToDos of one user to another user, if that is the case, you can store them in the same document only (However there is a max MongoDB BSON Document Size limit of `16MB`)

You can look into MongoDB array operators like

- `$push` to add items to the add
- `$pull` to remove items from the add
- `$filter` to get only certain items based on different conditions ( say a unique `todo_id`)

You can also check for `$unwind` (might be useful if you want to use aggregate pipeline`